# TensorflowJS TFJS error: The dtype of dict

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow.js, glitch-framework

Had tried to run https://glitch.com/~tar-understood-exoplanet
and the model would fail to load and I wouldn't be able to use enable the webcam.

Anyone had the same issue?

While the program is running, in the console I get the following:

```
tfjs:2 Uncaught (in promise) Error: The dtype of dict['image_tensor'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be int32, but was float32
    at Object.b [as assert] (tfjs:2)
    at tfjs:2
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t.checkInputShapeAndType (tfjs:2)
    at t.<anonymous> (tfjs:2)
    at tfjs:2
    at Object.next (tfjs:2)
    at tfjs:2
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Zv (tfjs:2)
```

I have a Macbook Pro and some other people on their Windows also had some issues running the model. We also tried it on different browsers, Safari and Chrome.

**SUCCESS! after switching to coco-ssd 2.0.2:**

I added the version 2.0.2 in line 62 as follows:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd@2.0.2"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting this Claire - I shall ask if any of the team know the answer on Monday!

Comment: For Chrome, it could be caused by that they rolled out a SameSite cookie policy on 04/04 that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the warmup run of coco-ssd that uses tf.zeros tensor. The default dtype for tf.zeros is 'float' in the recent release of TFJS. 
I have put out a new version with fixes. It should work if you use the latest version of coco-ssd (2.0.2) in the glitch example (index.html) as following.

```
    <!-- Load the coco-ssd model to use to recognize things in images -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd@2.0.2"></script>
```

Comment: See above please!

Comment: THe model loading code is commented out in index.js file (line 36-41)
The error seems to be irrelevant to TensorFlow.js

Answer (score 3):

Same error here, just occured since Friday night (04/03/2020)
TFModel works well in past few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.

**My Scenerio**:
I trained a pre-trained model from tensorflow model zoo using transfer learning using tensorflow api as saved model (model.pb file) and converted it into tfjs format (model.json and shared .bin files).

When I tried running this model.json on the javascript(web), it gives the below error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: The dtype of dict['input_tensor'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be int32, but was float32
```

When I tried someone else's working converted model (model.json and shared .bin files) on my javascript(web), it worked.

**Conclusion**:
There is something wrong with my converted model. I converted it using tensorflowjs_converter. My original model in (model.pb) works accurately in python too.

I'm still trying out to convert my model.pb file with different tensorflowjs_converters as it seems to be the converters versioning issue.

Comment: You can convert tensors dtype using `.toInt()` or as needed in my case `.toFloat()` https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.0.0/#tf.Tensor.toInt